# Como realizar async hasta que no cargue a la lista que llamo

Tags: flutter, dart

Tengo el siguiente error

`RangeError (index): Invalid value: Valid value range is empty: 0`

Se que es debido a que en este `ListView`, realiza una llamada a esta lista `_hrstotaleslist[i]` a la que no se le ha añadido ningún dato, ¿qué se puede hacer para cargar los datos antes y resolver este error?, o como realizar que espere hasta que tenga datos.

```
ListView _listViewUsuarios() {
    //lista de usuarios
    return  ListView.separated(
        physics: BouncingScrollPhysics(),
        itemBuilder: (_, i) =>
            _usuarioListTile(_usuariosbrigada[i], _hrstotaleslist[i]),
            separatorBuilder: (_, i) => Divider(),
            itemCount: _usuariosbrigada.length);
}
```

Gracias de antemano.

PD: cuando estando en esta pantalla refresco, funciona perfectamente, adjunto pantallas:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Answer (score 1):

Solucionado le he colocado este widget:

```
 body: FutureBuilder(
      future: _sumahorasbolsa_brigada(),
      builder: (BuildContext context, AsyncSnapshot snapshot) {
        print(snapshot.connectionState);
        if (snapshot.connectionState == ConnectionState.waiting) {
          return Center(child: CircularProgressIndicator());
        } else {
          return _listViewUsuarios();
        }
      }),
```